# How to get the values from the sqlite database using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite, cordova

how should we get the value from the sqlite  using java script as we give in android.

```
instance name = db.arraylistname(id);
column name =  instance name.get(0).get("column name");
```

how should we give it in java script?

how can we set text as we do in android such as,

```
text_view.setText(column name);
```

how should we give it in java script?whereas i have given the text as a listview's
data.

Rather,all the data in the "column name" should be viewed as a list view.

and normally,how should we settext for a tag as we do it for a text view in android.

i mean i would like to get a value from the database and place it in the content of the para tag `<p>....</p>`

please..help..i have no clue of it.

when i use the following coding to retrieve the data

```
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
{
    var obj = results.rows.item(i);
    console.log(+obj);               
}
```

i get the following in the log

```
04-17 11:54:59.416: D/CordovaLog(23307): Returned rows = 2
04-17 11:54:59.416: I/Web Console(23307): Returned rows = 2 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:33
04-17 11:54:59.416: D/CordovaLog(23307): NaN
04-17 11:54:59.416: I/Web Console(23307): NaN at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:38
04-17 11:54:59.427: D/CordovaLog(23307): NaN
04-17 11:54:59.427: I/Web Console(23307): NaN at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:38
04-17 11:54:59.427: D/CordovaLog(23307): No rows affected!
04-17 11:54:59.427: I/Web Console(23307): No rows affected! at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:44
```

i get **NaN** iwhereas i should get the data entered into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,i found the answer for first half of this question,

if we want the id from the table we need to code for phonegap

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) 
{
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
         console.log("Row = " + i + " id = " + results.rows.item(i).id);
     }
}
```

The exact code for retrieving the value is..

```
" id = " + results.rows.item(i).id
```